# SQL mental block - checking if one period of time overlaps another

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have four unix times. Two are the beginning and end of "today" (whichever that day may be) - i.e. 00:00:00 and 23:59:59 - and the other two are user-chosen times.

What I need is a (TSQL-friendly) query to check if the period between "today" times overlaps with the user's times. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have this in a txt doc to remember (date dyslexia):

**Intersects:**

```
Date Range 1   |         |>----------------------<|
Date Range 2   |                 |>------------------------<|

where Range1Start <= Range2End and Range1End >= Range2Start
```

**Range 1 in Range 2:**

```
Date Range 1   |                   |>-------------<|
Date Range 2   |                 |>------------------------<|


where Range1Start >= Range2Start and Range1End <= Range2End
```

**Range 2 in Range 1:**

```
Date Range 1   |         |>----------------------<|
Date Range 2   |                 |>-------------<|


where Range2Start >= Range1Start and Range2End <= Range1End
```

Answer (score 3):

```
where UserStart <= TodayEnd and
      UserEnd >= TodayStart
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old but I think the accepted answer is incomplete.There most be at least one more intersect case and modify the above.

**INTERSECT (FIXED)**

```
Date Range 1   |         |>----------------------<|
Date Range 2   |                 |>------------------------<|
WHERE Range1Start <= Range2Start AND Range1End <= Range2End AND Range1End>=Range2Start
```

Fixing like this allows to avoid detect Range 2 in Range 1 as an Intersection (which is the query result in the accepted solution)

The next two are OK but are not well illustrated

**Range 1 in Range 2**

```
Date Range 1   |                      |>-------------<|
Date Range 2   |                 |>------------------------<|

Date Range 1   |                 |>------------------------<|
Date Range 2   |                 |>------------------------<|

WHERE Range1Start >= Range2Start AND Range1End <= Range2End
```

**Range 2 in Range 1:**

```
Date Range 1   |         |>------------------------<|
Date Range 2   |               |>-------------<|

Date Range 1   |         |>------------------------<|
Date Range 2   |         |>------------------------<|


WHERE Range2Start >= Range1Start AND Range2End <= Range1End
```

And finally the second intersect

**INTERSECT (RIGHT)**

```
Date Range 1   |                |>----------------------<|
Date Range 2   |       |>------------------------<|
WHERE Range2Start <= Range1Start AND Range2End <= Range1End AND Range1Start <=Range2End
```

Depending on what you need I would suggest not using greater than (>=) and less than (<=) 'cause you also asume that equals period are in these groups but is up to you

**EQUALS RANGES**

```
Date Range 1   |         |>------------------------<|
Date Range 2   |         |>------------------------<|


WHERE Range1Start = Range2Start AND Range1End = Range2End
```